# how do you request a session from servicestack basic authentication, at /auth/basic?

Tags: authentication, servicestack, basic-authentication

I have set up a servicestack service with basic authentication using the first example, here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization

This automatically sets up a route: /auth/basic
However, I cannot find any information or examples on how to format a request to this URL (Variables/GET/POST/Auth Header, etc.).

I am able to access a simple service using the basic authentication credentials, so they are active and correct.

I have no custom authentication plugged in, just basic authentication.

I have tried:

- Using a JsonServiceClient to send UserName and Password variables by GET or Json POST to /auth/basic, with and without an Auth header also containing the user & pass.
- Using a browser to send GET requests with URL parameters of the user/pass, or as `http://user:pass@localhost:123/auth/basic`

I always just get "HTTP/1.1 401 Invalid BasicAuth credentials".

The only examples I can find involve some kind of custom authentication, and then /auth/credentials is accessed, but I want to use /auth/basic

I have looked at the code and it looks like it reads an Auth header, but the service does not accept one.

I am actually trying to get this working so I can then disable it and verify it is disabled (I want to require basic authentication for every request).

**Questions are:**

- What is the correct way to call the /auth/basic service? I will take a servicestack client API example, specifications or even a raw http request!
- How do you disable the /auth services altogether?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the correct way to call the /auth/basic service? I will take a servicestack client API example, specifications or even a raw http request!**

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:56006/api");
var resp = client.Post(new Auth() { UserName = "TestUser", Password = "Password" });
```

- This assumes you have also registered an `ICacheClient` and `IAuthUserRepository` (and added a user account)

The JSON format looks like this if you call into `/auth/basic?format=json`

```
{
  "UserName": "admin",
  "Password": "test"
  "RememberMe": true
}
```

**How do you disable the /auth services altogether?**

Don't add the `AuthFeature` plugin to configuration.

You can also [remove plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins#plugin-api)

```
Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is AuthFeature);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you add BasicAuthentication (for per-request authentication), the AuthFeature/sessions are added automatically. The question is, how can you disable the /auth sessions functionality, without disabling per-request authentication?

Comment: You can't -- `AuthFeature` plugin registers `SessionFeature` plugin and uses it. For basic auth on every call w/o session you can write custom `RequestFilterAttribute` implementation and decorate your services with this custom `[BasicAuthenticate]` attribute for instance.

Answer (score -1):

Putting the following in apphost config seems to do the trick.

```
//Disable most things, including SOAP support, /auth and /metadata routes
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig()
{
    EnableFeatures = Feature.Json | Feature.Xml
});
```

I am a little suspicious about what this does to /auth however, because it returns an empty response, while most routes return 404.

So, would this truly disable the /auth functionality? As in, if someone formed a correct request to /auth/credentials, will it still return an empty response?